# Getting page views and other data for a single URL (or similar URLs)

Tags: google-analytics-api

We're using the reporting APIs to access page views for specific page paths (using a regex match), but we're getting a lot of HTTP 500s and 503s, presumably because the requests are timing out due to the volume of data that needs to be scanned.

So, my question is, is there a way to access aggregate data for a URL? (for example, *all* page views, or *all* referrers)

Secondly, since a single resource can have multiple URLs (f.e. if the title forms part of the URL, and the title is changed), we would need to be able to get aggregate data for a set of URLs (using a regex, for example).

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this too simple... a query for pageviews with a filter that uses your regex expression? If the regex matches all variations of the URL, it would aggregate the results.  Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: @MikeSullivan That's what we're already doing, but it's too much data for GA to scan (too slow), so I was hoping that there were APIs for accessing pre-aggregated data.

Comment: I submitted an RFE @ https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=804

Comment: Perhaps you could break up the request into shorter date ranges. It means more processing client side but limits and quotas are in place to protect the underlying systems and also ensure equitable resource allocation to users.

Comment: @Matt I've considered that, but we have pages that are 10+ years old, so if that was broken down into 30 day units, it would require 120+ requests for a single page, and would be awkward to "reassemble". Also, this is not about quotas, it's about the amount of data that has to be processed, and could be solved by aggregation on the GA side. Thanks.